# java.lang.IllegalStateException Error in Android 9

Tags: android

Recently I am getting the following exception in Google Play console for the  Android version 9 users (users who have recently upgraded to ver 9 from ver 8).
Seems the exception is related to system class.
Does someone know the reason for this?

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3400)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:200)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1671)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:106)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6762)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:493)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:858) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1577) 
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1532)   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:664) 
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService
>   (ContextWrapper.java:664)   at
>   android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService
>   (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:89)   at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.c
>   (FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.java:11)   at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.a
>   (FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.java:72)   at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive
>   (FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.java:25)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3391)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:200)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1671)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:106)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6762)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:493)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: What dependency or FCM messaging you are using ? Is it latest one ?

Comment: @ADM it is com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0

Comment: That's like Stone Age Use [Latest Dependency](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0` and then Check .

Comment: @ADM Yes, this is an old app and we recently got this issue from some users who have upgraded to Android 9. Do you think old version causes for the issue? And also some devices which already have android 9 haven't got this issue.

Comment: Yeah this can be the version issue i think because of `java.lang.IllegalStateException` during `startService`. So i suggest update the build with latest dependency.

Comment: @ADM Thanks. I will check and let you know